# Let $H$ be the orthocentre of triangle $ABC$. Prove that the midpoints of $AB, AC, AH, BC, BH$ and $CH$ form a cyclic hexagon.

Tags: geometry

Let $H$ be the orthocentre of triangle $ABC$ ($H$ is the point inside triangle $ABC$ such that $AH ⊥ BC$,  and $BH ⊥ AC$ and $CH ⊥ AB$).  Prove that the midpoints of $AB, AC, AH, BC, BH$ and $CH$ form a cyclic hexagon.

Comment: You have posted six questions in the past day or so, each consisting of an isolated question. Typically, the community prefers questions that include some idea of what you know about the problem (what you've tried, why you're interested, where the problem comes from, what tools are allowed, etc) and/or where exactly you got stuck. Such information helps answerers target their responses to your skill level or specific difficulty, without wasting time telling you things you already know. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Answer (score 0):

The circumcirle of this hexagon it's the nine-point circle.

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle

Also, the following can help.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillium_theorem